# How to set Public Key DKIM in Postfix

Tags: postfix, dkim

I need to set up my public key in the postfix server, I already generated the keys in https://dkimcore.org/tools/, and added the TXT records in my DNS provider. But I have no idea how to set it in my postfix server, I'm checking for some tutorials on the internet but mostly use opendkim and I already have my keys.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Generating the private DKIM key on some random web site is quite irresponsible! The private key is called private because it should be kept private. Thus, the proper way to do it is to generate it locally, i.e. on your mailserver or your workstation via the `opendkim-genkey` command line tool.

Answer (score 2):

Run a DKIM signing filter/server like [opendkim](http://opendkim.org/) on the mail server.  This will listen on a local socket or port, like localhost:8891.  Then add that socket/port to `smtpd_milters` in your postfix config.

The [opendkim documentation](http://opendkim.org/docs.html) describes some more about this, and [postfix MILTER docs](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html) has details for the postfix side.